# SharePoint Online - Add 'documents' web part to page layout and allow changes to the web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, page-layout, designer, asp

I have created a custom wiki page layout which is almost perfect, however, I want to add a Document (Shared Document) web part to the page layout and allow the user to change the view of it when they create the page.

I have added the HTML code for the web part which displays the web part but it isn't editable? I have tried inserting it into a WebPartZone but this didn't show the web part, just a zone for the user to use.

[image]

1. The top box is a standard content box which I have manually inserted the 'Documents' WebPart and I get the drop down on the right which allows the user to edit it and change the view (what I want)
2. Is the 'Documents' WebPart that I have added to the Page Layout, which doesn't have the drop down on the right which allows the user to edit and change the view (what is happening and I don't want)

Here is the ASP code from the Page Layout.

```
        <h1>Documents</h1>

        <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ViewFlag="" ViewSelectorFetchAsync="False" InplaceSearchEnabled="False" ServerRender="False" ClientRender="True" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" IsClientRender="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" NoDefaultStyle="" ViewGuid="{09FBDF44-4990-45DB-BF80-23FA43ACEF04}" EnableOriginalValue="False" ViewContentTypeId="" ListUrl="" ListDisplayName="" ListName="{FE695577-E884-4A46-8B93-7D1DCB93BE4D}" ListId="fe695577-e884-4a46-8b93-7d1dcb93be4d" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" Title="Documents" FrameType="Default" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="This system library was created by the Publishing feature to store documents that are used on pages in this site." IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="wpz" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/itdl.png?rev=44" TitleUrl="/sites/ITIS-Wiki/Documents" DetailLink="/sites/ITIS-Wiki/Documents" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="/_layouts/15/images/itdl.png?rev=44" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="False" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_4ce4a5d5_e5af_44d2_93e4_c033cfbacc74" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{09FBDF44-4990-45DB-BF80-23FA43ACEF04}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="Fldtypes_mswhTitle.xsl;fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><ParameterBindings>
        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
                <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
                <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
                <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
                <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" /><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" /><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)" /></ParameterBindings>
        <DataFields>
        </DataFields>
        <XmlDefinition>
        <View Name="{09FBDF44-4990-45DB-BF80-23FA43ACEF04}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="" Url="/sites/ITIS-Wiki/SitePages/test.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/dlicon.png?rev=44" ><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef"/></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/><FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/><FieldRef Name="Modified"/><FieldRef Name="Editor"/></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink><XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="Standard"/></View></XmlDefinition>
        </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart> 

        <h1>Support</h1>
        <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="e92a70e3-1ac3-42a7-b5ce-86c8ccdedc4a" runat="server"></PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>
```

How can I make it editable?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: Sorry, I have now read the tour :)